# Accurate method for finding the time complexity of a function

Tags: c, for-loop, time-complexity

How to find the time complexity of this function:

**Code**

```
void f(int n)
{
    for(int i=0; i<n; ++i)
        for(int j=0; j<i; ++j)
            for(int k=i*j; k>0; k/=2)
               printf("~");
}
```

I took an educated guess of `(n^2)*log(n)` based on intuition and it turned out to be correct.

But I can't seem to find an accurate explanation for it.

Comment: Seems like the only tough part is how to deal with `k=i*j`.  That can be handled by realizing that `log(n^2) = 2log(n)` and big-O ignores constants.

Comment: Indeed that's true, I've noticed these things but the thing is, like you said, the i*j part is confusing. The innermost loop executes log(i*j) times, so we have some sort of sum here that I cannot seem to formulate accurately

Comment: Ah, I understand. You're looking for the exact formula, like `1+2+3+...+n = n(n+1)/2`. I'm not sure there is such a formula for this code, but you can try your luck on the [math stack exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For every value of `i`, `i>0`, there will be `i-1` values of the inner loop, each of them for `k` starting respectively at:

```
i*1, i*2, ..., i(i-1)
```

Since `k` is divided by `2` until it reaches `0`, each of these inner-inner loops require `lg(k)` steps. Hence

```
lg(i*1) + lg(i*2) + ... + lg(i(i-1)) = lg(i) + lg(i) + lg(2) + ... + lg(i) + lg(i-1)
                                     = (i-1)lg(i) + lg(2) + ... + lg(i-1)
```

Therefore the total would be

```
f(n) ::= sum_{i=1}^{n-1} i*lg(i) + lg(2) + ... + lg(i-1)
```

Let's now bound `f(n+1)` from above:

```
f(n+1) <= sum_{i-1}^n i*lg(i) + (i-1)lg(i-1)
       <= 2*sum_{i-1}^n i*lg(i)
       <= C*integral_0^n x(ln x)            ; integral bound, some constant C
        = C/2(n^2(ln n) - n^2/2)            ; integral x*ln(x) = x^2/2*ln(x) - x^2/4
        = O(n^2*lg(n))
```

If we now bound `f(n+1)` from below:

```
f(n+1) >= sum_{i=1}^n i*lg(i)
       >= C*integral_0^n x(ln x)            ; integral bound
        = C*(n^2*ln(n)/2 - n^2/4)           ; integral x*ln(x) = x^2/2*ln(x) - x^2/4
       >= C/4(n^2*ln(n))
        = O(n^2*lg(n))
```